# How to check Octave file dependencies

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm trying to grab some MATLAB scripts and execute them using octave. Is it possible to automatically check if the files won't complain about missing functions?

I ask this because I've already tried running it, and found a couple of problems which took long to resolve, so maybe there's a way to check this beforehand and see if it's worth the problem of translating the script.

Also, in case there are any external tools available to do this, I am running octave under Ubuntu 13.04

Thanks.

Comment: Octave does not compile or analyse the code before interpreting, as far as I understood this makes such features impossible.

Comment: What you are asking is not possible without running the code.  Since the reason you are doing it is to know if the code will run in Octave, you cannot do it in Octave.

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB, move to the folder containing your script. Then right-click in the Current Folder Browser, and select Reports->Dependency Report.

That should list all the files in your current folder, along with a list of all the other files that they depend on.

You can accomplish something similar at the command line using (in old versions of MATLAB, pre-14a) the command `depfun` or (in newer versions, post-14a) the command `matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts`.

Comment: Yep. I was pretty much asking for an equivalent in Octave. Since there are some functions in some matlab Toolbox that are present in many octave packages, but some others are not.

Comment: Sorry, sounds like I misunderstood the question.